# Python IDLE multiple statement error is shell mode

Tags: python, shell, syntax, compiler-errors, python-idle

I have a trouble with my IDLE.
When I typing some code, the error occured.

SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement...

But I find many many solutions to solve this error, but anyone can't help my case.

import turtle as t

t.shape("turtle")

this is all of my code.
I typed the code line one by one and press enter.
I checked the blank.
Not Copy and Paste. Only hands.

[image: the screenshot of my idle.]

Comment: I am quite puzzled.  I have the same 3.9.1 from Dec 7 on Windows 10.  When I type `import turtle as t` and hit return, turtle is immediately imported and I get a new `>>>` prompt.  There is no possibility of typing `t.shape...` before that.  Perhaps you should try rerunning the installer and select 'repair'.  That is almost never needed, but I don't know what else to suggest.

Comment: I discovered how to reproduce moving the cursor to a new line without triggering a compile, etc.  At the end of the import line, hit Control-J, which is the newline character, and which moves the cursor when echoed.  The Enter keys send different keycodes to the tcl/tk keypress event handler.  But it looks like on your system, <Enter> is sometimes being interpreted as or seen as ^J.